# Scanning in file

Tags: java, file, arraylist, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to scan the following sentences into my Java program as strings:

```
The cat in the hat
The cat sat on the mat
Pigs in a blanket
```

and then read it into a list using `while`loop and `hasNextLine()`method.
My problem is that I am unsure how to read this in as it is not a designated text file and I must utilize`args [0]`

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Scan {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

        //Opens a scanner into the file
        File file = new File( args [0] );
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(file))
        {
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

            while(scan.hasNextLine())
            {
                list.add(scan.nextLine());
              }
        }

}
}
```

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: I guess I'm just having trouble outputting it just to check and make sure I did it right? When I run the program I'm not getting the desired output of the file

Comment: @Beginner `it is not a designated text file` --> Where are you expecting your input from?

Comment: As a command line parameter? Which I'm guessing that's not something I can just check in the IDE @iRuth?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to output the list, use a for each style loop is the fastest way to check if you're doing it right.

```
for (String val : list)
{
   System.out.println(val);
}
```

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace your existing code with the one below:

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        list.add(scan.nextLine());
    }

    scan.close();
```

Use `System.in` instead of `new File(args[0])`. `System.in` reads from the standard input (i.e. whatever is entered in with the keyboard). This should work both on an IDE and with command line input.

I hope this helps.